# Unable to use set static IP on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04

I'm trying to setup a static IP on an interface in Ubuntu 16.04. I've tried doing it from the interfaces file and the Edit Connections GUI as well.

I've searched around and found several similar questions (Unable to properly set static IP in Ubuntu 16.04), but it didn't help my problem.

Eventually I will need to have three devices connected to a switch and able to speak to each other, but for now setting a static ip for each machine is the main focus.

16.04 /etc/network/interfaces file:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto enp2s0
iface enp2s0 inet static
address 192.168.1.10
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.0.1
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

I've tried using 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4, just 8.8.8.8, and 8.8.8.8 192.168.0.1 for the dns-nameservers.

Also my steps for restarting the network:

```
$ sudo ip addr flush enp2s0 && sudo systemctl restart networking.service
```

Then checking with:

```
$ ifconfig
enp2s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 84:2b:2b:9f:ba:45  
      inet addr:192.168.1.10  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::e4c4:1a45:c10e:ffb0/64 Scope:Link
      inet6 addr: 2001:579:80cc:3900:b196:e123:f5ce:f6d9/64 Scope:Global
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:3467 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:1947 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:3333106 (3.3 MB)  TX bytes:291202 (291.2 KB)
      Interrupt:16
```

Everything looks fine, and it is trying to use the static ip that I've set.  However I cannot ping any sites, as there is no internet connection.

```
Address: 192.168.1.10
Netmask: 255.255.255.0
Gateway: 192.168.0.1
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

If you need any other info just let me know.

Thanks.

Edit 1: Thanks for the solution! If anyone is having a similar problem double check to make sure your gateway address is correct.  Mine was incorrect and happened to be `192.168.0.1`. Then any ip address I wanted to assign it had to have the same subnet as well, i.e. `192.168.0.x`, as explained by @Pilot6

Comment: Can you ping `192.168.1.1`?

Comment: I added the ping statistics to the end of the question.  It wouldn't ping 192.168.1.1

Comment: So why do you expect to go somewhere through the `192.168.1.1` gateway if you can't ping it? Is there any device in your network with this address? Why did you choose this address as a gateway?

Comment: If you don't have an Internet connection, and specifically a NAT router on address 192.168.1.1, then why would you expect this to work?

Comment: I'm sorry I am new to ubuntu and ip configurations.  I am assuming the default route is the gateway address?

Comment: It is not related to Ubuntu. Yes, the default route is the gateway address, but you don't have anything with this address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You successfully setup a static IP, but you've set `192.168.1.1` as a gateway that doesn't exist.

You can connect to other computers connected to the same switch with other IPs from this subnet. But you can't get anywhere else from there until you set a valid gateway.

And your IP address should be in the same subnet as the gateway.

Comment: Alright, so after using 'route' I found the correct gateway is 192.168.0.1, however I still cannot ping it when I restart my network

Comment: Set the address to `192.168.0.10` then ;-) You need to be in the same subnet. Then you'll be able to ping 192.168.0.1.

Comment: it worked!! thanks for baring with my lack of knowledge on the subject!